# BigQuery convert String to Date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my dataset, one column called timestamp was created with datatype as **String**.

It contains values like:

**2018-05-30T12:56:27:487+0200**

I want to construct a query where I can fetch all column from the dataset table based on the date in **'YYYY-MM-DD' format**.

I want to use it in where clause with DATE Range between.

Can you guide?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the `:487` a typo?

Comment: No I guess, it was copied from dynamo db of aws to bigquery dataset. values are in production, existing. We are migrating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> convert String to Date

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2018-05-30T12:56:27.487+0200' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-05-30T01:56:27.487+0200' 
)
SELECT ts AS ts_as_string, 
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E3S%z', ts) ts_as_timestamp,
  DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E3S%z', ts)) ts_as_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
ts_as_string                    ts_as_timestamp                 ts_as_date   
2018-05-30T12:56:27.487+0200    2018-05-30 10:56:27.487 UTC     2018-05-30   
2018-05-30T01:56:27.487+0200    2018-05-29 23:56:27.487 UTC     2018-05-29
```

As you can see - first i am parsing timestamp out of the string - this is important part - this is where you can take timezone into account (see difference in dates in the result `2018-05-29` vs. `2018-05-29`). Then you can get Date out of TIMESTAMP

> I want to use it in where clause with DATE Range between.

So, now you can use below in your WHERE clause

```
WHERE DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E3S%z', ts)) BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

> Update

You can use below to avoid dealing with "wrong" format

```
PARSE_DATE('%F',  SUBSTR(ts, 1, 10))
```

In case if you need to account for timezone  - you can use below (which fix `:` to `.` before applying PARSE_TIMESTAMP)

```
DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E3S%z', FORMAT('%s.%s', SUBSTR(ts, 1, 19), SUBSTR(ts, 21, 8))))
```

Comment: Many thanks Mikhail. I used it: `select * from iotdata.Barcelona where MacAddress='b5:54:1f:fb:d6:11' and 
DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E3S%z', Timestamp)) = PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d','2018-05-30');` It throws error as **Failed to parse input string "2018-05-30T12:56:27:487+0200"**

Comment: this is because of `:487` part - it should of been `.487` - see update

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. Yet to have a competency in Bigquery it is my first project using it. So far used only RDMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date in the same timezone represented, then the simplest method is to use string operations and convert to a date:

```
select PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', SUBSTR('2018-05-30T12:56:27:487+0200', 1, 10))
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks. To be precise, I want to do it like : select * from iotdata.Barcelona where MacAddress='a5:54:1e:fb:d6:11' and 
DATE(SUBSTR(Timestamp, 1, 10))= '2018-05-30' but it throws error: No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: DATE(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATE(DATETIME); DATE(INT64, INT64, INT64) at [2:1]

Comment: @Arindam . . . That gets me every time, because it works with a fixed string.  So, `DATE('2018-01-01')` works, but `DATE(SUBSTR('2018-01-01', 1, 10))` does not.  Of course, `PARSE_DATE()` is the fix.