# Bigquery: Change format of dates from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, date, parsing, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that contains multiple date fields that follow one of these two formats:

String_datatype_field: 2004-01-21 12:23:21

OR

Date_datatype_field: 2004-04-21

The string date having the more specific time down to seconds while the date type fields having just the date.

How would I go about parsing/converting these fields and changing them into 21/04/2004 (dd/mm/yyyy) format? Thanks

EDIT:
I've found how to do it for the date fields:
FORMAT_DATE("%m/%d/%Y", Date_datatype_field)
just need string fields.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763187/bigquery-convert-string-to-date#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20the%20date%20in%20the%20same,date%3A%20select%20PARSE_DATE%20%28%27%25Y-%25m-%25d%27%2C%20SUBSTR%20%28%272018-05-30T12%3A56%3A27%3A487%2B0200%27%2C%201%2C%2010%29%29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763187/bigquery-convert-string-to-date#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20the%20date%20in%20the%20same,date%3A%20select%20PARSE_DATE%20%28%27%25Y-%25m-%25d%27%2C%20SUBSTR%20%28%272018-05-30T12%3A56%3A27%3A487%2B0200%27%2C%201%2C%2010%29%29) useful. I think you can just cast the string as a date, then use the `FORMAT_DATE` function you already found to get it to your desired format.